# How can I use absolute include paths in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on importing a C++ eclipse cdt project into  cmake, while changing as little code as possible. Now I have run into an issue. Eclipse sets include paths relative to the file itself, while the project using cmake uses paths realtive to the source directory. So basicly imaging this file structure:

```
-Main
--Main.cpp
-Header.h
```

in eclipse you would do this:

```
#include "../Header.cpp"
```

while in cmake you would do this:

```
#include "Header.cpp"
```

So I basicly now need a way to make eclipse work the second way. Is there some kind of setting I can use for this?

Comment: Add an include path (Project->Properties->C/C++->Paths and Symbols Includes Tab) to the root of the headers.

Comment: thanks, that helped

Comment: I would not do as the comment suggested since when you re-run cmake, it will blow away your changes. Those mods are not reproducable for others trying to build the project UNLESS you include the eclipse CDT solution files (which defeats the point of using CMake).

Comment: OK, I'll probably just end up adding the new files manually everytime anyway, since a clean solution probably beats less maintenance. But not having new files automaticly picked up just seams like such  a non-programmer thing to do.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether you use CMake to generate the Eclipse project, or set up the Eclipse project yourself. @g19fanatic's concern only applies in the first case.

Comment: Now I have an eclipse projected that needs to be converted into a cmake project, so basicly replace eclipse with cmake and makefiles.

Comment: One solution i've had to do in the past with CDT is to create a 'patch' that adds the stdlib locations to the generated CDT project file. The patch would be commited into SCM and there would be a custom step in the cmake to apply the patch after everything was generated.